# handling complex corrupted json using Pyspark

Tags: json, pyspark

I have data from message route from ioTHub. While dumps the data into blob in json format. I need to read that json using pyspark. That json contains encoded as well as decoded data, while reading data the encoded data is coming properly but the decoded json is giving trouble. It is taking each line of json as a row in dataframe and these are created under corrupted records.I need to handle this and not miss any data from corrupt records. Multiline, permissive doesn't work.

Handle the data and not miss any data from courrupt records

df= spark.read.json("path")
df.show()

[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aGBG.png

Comment: Please add your input data, expected output and whatever code you've written to achieve the scenario. This will help the community to provide a better solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.